# How to update 2 separate nodes in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I have problems with transactions using Firebase. I want to update 2 nodes (models and scenes) at the same time but it never updates my database.

Here is my code:

```
public static void Delete(DataContainers.Scene iScene)
    {
        DatabaseReference leaderBoardRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        leaderBoardRef.RunTransaction(mutableData =>
        {

            mutableData.Child("Scenes/" + iScene.id).Value = null;
            foreach (var _model in iScene.models)
            {
                mutableData.Child("models/" + _model).Value = null;
            }
            return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
        });
    }
```

Is there any other way how to do it?

Comment: I don't immediately see something wrong with the code. Are other database updates in your app working correctly? If so, can you update the same locations *without* a transaction? If so, if you step through the code, are the values of `iScene.id` and `_model` what you expect them to be?

Comment: I can delete them without transaction but its not best way, so i would like to use transactions, and yes those values are corect. If I want to delete just one node then it works fine, but if i try to update 2 nothing happens. That lambda function repeats itself I thing 25 times bud nothings changes in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [multi-path update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#update_specific_fields) to delete all the data at once like you desire:

```cs
private void deleteScene(DataContainers.Scene iScene) {
    // Get root database reference
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

    // Initialize a new list of "path->value" pairs
    Dictionary<string, Object> childUpdates = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

    // Delete the given scene and all of its models
    childUpdates["/Scenes/" + iScene.id] = null;
    foreach (var _model in iScene.models)
    {
        childUpdates["/models/" + _model] = null;
    }

    mDatabase.UpdateChildrenAsync(childUpdates);
}
```

Comment: well that looks fine, but is is same as running a transactions ??? isn't it posible that only scenes updates,than i lose conection and models never updates ???

Comment: Transactions are read->modify->write operations and an update is just a write operation. Both of these write operations are atomic - i.e. all or nothing.

Comment: Ok, thanks, its working and if you say it atomic its just what i was looking for

Comment: Great answer Sam. @NikodémAdler The problem with your transaction based approach is that you're updating two nodes in completely different parts of the database tree. If any other node in that same tree is being updated around the same time, your transaction will be retried, which aborts after 25 tries. For that reason transactions really only work well if you're updating data that is close to each other in the JSON. In cases where you don't need the current value of a node to determine its new value, multi-location updates like Sam shows are way more efficient and scalable.